# Single page site navigation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not trying to create a vertical scroll or smooth scroll, I get confused when putting jquery together because I am so new to it. I know I need to create a function with a parameter to accept what the section name will be in coordination with my link.
I have a main section that will display with a full nav, when the user clicks on the nav item I want the main section to hide, then I want to add an active class to only display the content of the next "page" / section.

I created jsfiddle.

```
$(document).on('click','.nav-link',function(e){
    $('.section').closest('div').addClass('active');

});

function content(dv){
var dv = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link[data-target]');
console.log(dv);

}
content();
```

my html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrapper-menu">
    <!-- navigation -->
        <header>    
            <nav class="slide-in menu">
                <ul class="hide">
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="go" class="nav-link">Go dog go<span></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="by" class="nav-link">Stop dog stop<span></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="bike" class="nav-link">To a dog party<span></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r_heneault/jyvzxeha/5/

I know I am overthinking something that is simplistic :|

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Rachel: If any of the answers below helped, I'd encourage you to up-vote them (click the "up-arrow" above the large number to the left).  If any of them were "the answer" to your question, then I'd encourage you to "accept" the answer by clicking the gray checkbox underneath the number to the left.  This is how users earn "reputation" on the site - up-votes and accepts to the answers they provide.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide some element of your content, you can check an example in my jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("li").click(function(){
        var a = $(this).attr('name')
     $("#"+a).hide();
});
```

});

because what i get in your question is how to make some content visible or hidden.
ps : editted.
https://jsfiddle.net/hfahrudin/jyvzxeha/7/

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!

While I'd suggest tweaking your markup slightly to make hiding the sections that should NOT be visible easier, I've adjusted your fiddle to do what I believe you are asking: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/jyvzxeha/6/)

Note:
The key is to (keep it simple, use jQuery), and get the id from the link (via `.data('target')`), then use that id to show the relevant div.

The relevant changes to your script are below:

```
$(document).on('click','.nav-link',function(e){
    // get the div ID from the link's "data-target"
    var id = $(this).data('target');
    // hide ALL divs with the id
    $('.section > div[id]').hide();
    // show only the relevant div with the targeted ID
    $('#' + id).show();
});
```

**Alternate:**

If your goal is to show hide the relevant `div.section`, then again - I'd suggest modifying your markup to make this simpler.  However, you can do so with your current markup given this jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.nav-link',function(e){
  // get the ID
  var id = $(this).data('target');
  // hide all sections
  $('.section').hide();
  // show the section that contains the div with the target ID
  $('#' + id).closest('.section').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks all - this helped a lot. I can't believe how long it took me to figure this out.  I had a conflict in my jquery with another section.  Live and learn, at least NOW I get what I did and will hopefully not repeat that issue! :)  Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want...

So, you need to give the li id's to use as selectors with jQuery.

Then make all of the section divs display: none; with their id's.

Then create .active that is display: inherit !important;

Give one of the divs class="active" from the start.

So when li#go_go is clicked it removes .active from the other divs, then adds .active to #go.

The same is true for the others.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#go_go').click(function() {
      $('#by').removeClass('active');
      $('#bike').removeClass('active');
      $('#go').addClass('active');
    })
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stop_stop').click(function() {
      $('#go').removeClass('active');
      $('#bike').removeClass('active');
      $('#by').addClass('active');
    })
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bike_bike').click(function() {
      $('#go').removeClass('active');
      $('#by').removeClass('active');
      $('#bike').addClass('active');
    })
  });
```

```css
div#go {
      display: none;
    }

    div#by {
      display: none;
    }

    div#bike {
      display: none;
    }

    .active {
      display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <div class="wrapper-menu">
 <!-- navigation -->
    <header>
     <nav class="slide-in menu">
    <ul class="hide">
     <li id="go_go"><a href="#" data-target="go" class="nav-link">Go dog go<span></span></a></li>
     <li id="stop_stop"><a href="#" data-target="by" class="nav-link">Stop dog stop<span></span></a></li>
     <li id="bike_bike"><a href="#" data-target="bike" class="nav-link">To a dog party<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
 </div>
</div>


<ul id="content" class="layer">
 <li> <!-- about -->
  <div class="section light">
   <div id="go" class="active">
   <a name="go"></a>
    <div class="content">
       <h2>Go</h2>
     <p>Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.
Cum horribilem walking dead resurgere de crazed sepulcris creaturis, zombie sicut de grave feeding iride et serpens. Pestilentia, shaun ofthe dead scythe animated corpses ipsa screams. Pestilentia est plague haec decaying ambulabat mortuos. Sicut zeder apathetic malus voodoo. Aenean a dolor plan et terror soulless vulnerum contagium accedunt, mortui iam vivam unlife. Qui tardius moveri, brid eof reanimator sed in magna copia sint terribiles undeath legionis. Alii missing oculis aliorum sicut serpere crabs nostram. Putridi braindead odores kill and infect, aere implent left four dead.</p>
     <div>
      <h3>No</h3>

     </div>
    </div>
    </div>  <!-- section -->
 </li>

 <li> <!-- about -->
  <div class="section light">
   <div id="by">
   <a name="by"></a>
    <div class="content">
       <h2>BY</h2>
     <p>Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.
Cum horribilem walking dead resurgere de crazed sepulcris creaturis, zombie sicut de grave feeding iride et serpens. Pestilentia, shaun ofthe dead scythe animated corpses ipsa screams. Pestilentia est plague haec decaying ambulabat mortuos. Sicut zeder apathetic malus voodoo. Aenean a dolor plan et terror soulless vulnerum contagium accedunt, mortui iam vivam unlife. Qui tardius moveri, brid eof reanimator sed in magna copia sint terribiles undeath legionis. Alii missing oculis aliorum sicut serpere crabs nostram. Putridi braindead odores kill and infect, aere implent left four dead.</p>
     <div>
      <h3>No</h3>

     </div>
    </div>
    </div>  <!-- section -->
 </li>
 <li> <!-- about -->
  <div class="section light">
   <div id="bike">
   <a name="bike"></a>
    <div class="content">
       <h2>Bike</h2>
     <p>Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.
Cum horribilem walking dead resurgere de crazed sepulcris creaturis, zombie sicut de grave feeding iride et serpens. Pestilentia, shaun ofthe dead scythe animated corpses ipsa screams. Pestilentia est plague haec decaying ambulabat mortuos. Sicut zeder apathetic malus voodoo. Aenean a dolor plan et terror soulless vulnerum contagium accedunt, mortui iam vivam unlife. Qui tardius moveri, brid eof reanimator sed in magna copia sint terribiles undeath legionis. Alii missing oculis aliorum sicut serpere crabs nostram. Putridi braindead odores kill and infect, aere implent left four dead.</p>
     <div>
      <h3>No</h3>

     </div>
    </div>
    </div>  <!-- section -->
 </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Oh, and don't forget to link jQuery.

Best, 
Levi

Answer (score 0):

simplest would be this:

replace `href="#" data-target="go"` with `href="#go"` and so on

```
$('.nav-link').on('click',function(e){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(e.target.getAttribute('href')).closest('div').addClass('active');

});
```

and adding css like this:

```
.section.light > div {
  display:none;
}

.section.light > .active {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One key piece that is tripping you up is that you're adding an active class to all of the content on any click of a link, and it does not get removed at any point. Another is that you have no css that is hiding and displaying the content based on the classes you give it. The active class is attached, but has no instruction to actually do anything, which you would want to set in the css.

Take a look at the following code / fiddle for a working example of what you're looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > li > a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//stop browser to take action for clicked anchor

    //get displaying tab content jQuery selector
    var active_tab_selector = $('.nav-tabs > li.active > a').attr('href');

    //find actived navigation and remove 'active' css
    var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs > li.active');
    actived_nav.removeClass('active');

    //add 'active' css into clicked navigation
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

    //hide displaying tab content
    $(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active');
    $(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');

    //show target tab content
    var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
    $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
     });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/messerino/thwxnddn/